# How to calculate distance on screen in pixels corresponding to a certain angle, knowing camera's FOV and screen resolution?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to re-create how a certain videogame handles weapon recoil.

For example, there is a value of `recoil_magnitude`, which describes a vertical "kick" of the weapon, in degrees. I want to convert that value to a *distance in pixels* my crosshair has moved on the screen, knowing that angle, FOV (Field Of View, in degrees) of the camera, and the resolution of the screen (in pixels).

The first idea i had was to not overthink it and try to calculate it directly - by dividing `vertical screen resolution` by `recoil_magnitude` and multiplying it by my `FOV` - but testing showed that this formula is (unsurprisingly) inaccurate.

Any ideas how I would approach this?

Comment: Sounds like a pixel-scaling problem, I think power-scalers will be helpful here. See if this thread helps. https://vsbattles.com/threads/pixel-scaling-and-pixel-conversion.83817/ There are even a lot of examples using pixel-scaling to obtain results on that site

Comment: This result may help you understand the process as well. https://vsbattles.fandom.com/wiki/User_blog:Amelia_Lonelyheart/Beyblade:_Galaxy_Pegasus